# Where to define NSArray and where to define Button action?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have made an array of text strings and want to pull these out an into a label by EITHER swiping of pressing a button. So i have two different functions/methods, the button and the swipe method.

Where and how do I define the array so that these methods can refer to it? Should it be a 'extern NSArray' ?

I have uploaded the image of full code externally http://s1.postimg.org/b2e3m4v67/Sk_rmbillede_2014_05_11_kl_15_48_28.png
Not sure though if that's a violation of some rules here(?)

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials and code examples for such declarations in the web. Did you try to find those?

Comment: Have tried searching around yes. But I find it difficult what to search for exactly. One thread suggested defining the variables in the header file, but that made the application fail when I tried to run it - so I skipped that way of doing it.

Comment: any links would be much appreciated. I have been searching for an hour now and cannot find much useful.

Comment: Please try to improve your question (and add code). I think I still don't get what exactly your are asking. You can define an array in the header or in a class extension. What do you mean with button action? The method which is called when an event happens on the button? If so, the button action should be defined in the implementation. But I don't know why one would ask that.

Comment: I'm trying to put in the entire code of my .m file, but I haven't found a way to treat a whole section of text as code in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the quote to change on swipe/button press.

In your button press/swipe methods you're setting the text property of the VC's label property to something called Quoteselected. And it looks like Quoteselected is a random element of the array Quotes - or at least maybe it is, since that random number could be 6-10, and you don't have any objects in the Quotes array at those indices - so if those numbers are ever generated by the random function, your program will crash due to an index out of bounds error.

What you probably want to do is generate a new random number on each user interaction and then at that point change the value of Quoteselected to be the object at that index of the array. And then assign that to the label's text property.

As far as defining the Array - I wouldn't have done it the way you did. What you've got there is an "ivar", an instance variable. On iOS, those are typically properties. And since it's a "private" array that outside classes won't need to know about, I'd declare it as a part of the class extension.

So,

```
@interface BOViewController()
@property NSArray *quotes;
@end
```

Also note my capitalization changes, that's better style.

So now you've got an array property declared, but there's no data in it. It depends on how you created your View Controller instance. Assuming you did it in a storyboard, it would go in awakeFromNib: or viewDidLoad: (if you instantiated the VC automatically, you might put it in the initWithNibName: method).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   self.quotes = @[@"Test", @"Number 3"...];
```

Then when you want to reference the array in other parts of the class:

```
self.label.text = self.quotes[0];
```

Note that your existing code should work, it's just not typical Cocoa coding style.

Comment: I get what you're suggesting there. But really what I need is to just be able to declare/define my Array(and 2 variables) once and for all and then be able to refer to this later on in the code.

I think that will be easier, because even if I were to try it your way, I simply wouldn't know where to put the different parts of the code. So far in my projects I've only used my variables for one method - so I've never had to have multiple methods get access to one variable

Comment: Isn't it possible to define a global Array that any number of methods can refer to?